# how to hide Quick suggestions on keyboard in titanium mobile for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, titanium-mobile

while typing text some space is added to keyboard and Text Suggestions are showing up i would like to disable those suggestions in my application.Please let me know how to do.

tss code

```
"#emailtextfield[platform=android]":{
top: "3%",
height: "6%",
width: '70%',
paddingLeft: 5,
borderRadius: 3,
font:{
    fontSize: Alloy.Globals.smallfont
},
backgroundColor: '#000000',
opacity: '0.5',
color: '#fff',
autocorrect:false,
autocapitalization: Ti.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
softKeyboardOnFocus: Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS,
keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL
},
"#passwordtextfield[platform=android]":{
top: "2%",
height: "6%",
width: '70%',
paddingLeft: 5,
borderRadius: 3,
autocorrect:false,
font:{
    fontSize: Alloy.Globals.smallfont
},
backgroundColor: '#000000',
opacity: '0.5',
color: '#fff',
autocapitalization: Ti.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
softKeyboardOnFocus: Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS,
keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL
}
```

xml code

```
<TextField id="emailtextfield" hintText="Email/Username"></TextField>
<TextField id='passwordtextfield'hintText="Password"passwordMask="true"></TextField>
```

Comment: This question doesnot belong to this community

Comment: goto the android.stackexchange.com webiste .. or play around your settings tab, on your phone

Comment: I am guessing he's asking how to do it programmatically for only his application instead of altering the device's settings which would require intrusive permissions. The soft keyboard can be manipulated from the InputMethodManager, take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-autocorrect) I see a property called `autocorrect` for the text field. It should help you. Set it to false.

Edit: It turns out `autocorrect` and `suggestion` are two different things. The suggestions can be turned off from your keyboard's settings. On android there can be multiple keyboards so verify the one you are using. Whereas autocorrect is text field property used to replace the misspelled words.

Comment: The property is not working in both iOS and Android? Can you show the code you are using to create the text field?

Comment: The thing is only for few fields suggestions are showed up and for some fields they r not...:(

Comment: Pls update your question with the code used to create the fields.